# Installing Print-Server on windows docker contaiener container fails

Tags: windows, powershell, docker-compose, windows-container

I am running a fresh `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019`
The first thing I try to do is  install `Print-Server` but gives me an error (It is the first time I am installing a windows feature with powershell):

```
add-WindowsFeature -Name Print-Server

add-WindowsFeature : The request to add or remove features on the specified server failed.
Installation of one or more roles, role services, or features failed.
The source files could not be found.
Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source
location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077. Error: 0x800f081f
At line:1 char:1
+ add-WindowsFeature -Name Print-Services -IncludeAllSubFeature
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (@{Vhd=; Credent...Name=localhost}:PSObject) [Install-WindowsFeature], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DISMAPI_Error__Failed_To_Enable_Updates,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.AddWindowsFeatureCommand
```

I have tried to mount my host `WinSxS` inside the container and use the sources folder , but I get the same error.

```
Install-WindowsFeature -Name Print-Server -Source c:\sources
```

I have also tried online with `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature` but gives me this error :

```
PS C:\> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Print-Server
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : Feature name Print-Server is unknown.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Print-Server
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand
```

Looking at other questions this part seams to be working for other people. I am running windows 10 enterprise 2004.
Does someone know what can I do ?

Comment: I have the same issue trying to install docker on windows server 2019 image, so interested in any support you get.  Install-WindowsFeature containers

Answer (score 1):

[From here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/print-spooler):

> The mcr.microsoft.com/windows image should be the targeted base image.
> Other Windows container base images (such as Nano Server and Windows
> Server Core) do not carry the Printing Server Role.